# creating a new lambda function by integrating

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, lambda, scipy

I have an existing function defined in Python using a `lambda` function.  The function represents the PDF of a probability distribution.  I would like to construct another `lambda` function one-liner which represents the CDF.

I do not wish to use a separate function definition with the `def` keyword.

Below is the code portion I've been working with:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.integrate as integrate

#define range
dx=0.01
X  = np.arange(0,13,dx)

#define a piecewise function for the spline
ul = 1.0
f_pdf = lambda x: np.piecewise(x, [x < ul, x >= ul], [x[x<ul],0])
f_cdf = lambda x: integrate.quad(f_pdf,0,x)

#print the function evaluations
print(f_pdf(X))
print(f_cdf(X))
```

Note that I recently found that for the piecewise definition I needed to restrict the range on the returned array in the `x<ul` case like `x[x<ul]` in order for this to work correctly with different size arrays.

The error I get from the last command includes:

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-ff6550e6092c> in <module>()
     13 #print the function evaluations
     14 print(f_pdf(X))
---> 15 print(f_cdf(X))

<ipython-input-4-ff6550e6092c> in <lambda>(x)
      9 ul = 1.0
     10 f_pdf = lambda x: np.piecewise(x, [x < ul, x >= ul], [x[x<ul],0])
---> 11 f_cdf = lambda x: integrate.quad(f_pdf,0,x)
     12 
     13 #print the function evaluations

/path/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/integrate/quadpack.py in quad(func, a, b, args, full_output, epsabs, epsrel, limit, points, weight, wvar, wopts, maxp1, limlst)
    321     if (weight is None):
    322         retval = _quad(func, a, b, args, full_output, epsabs, epsrel, limit,
--> 323                        points)
    324     else:
    325         retval = _quad_weight(func, a, b, args, full_output, epsabs, epsrel,

/path/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/integrate/quadpack.py in _quad(func, a, b, args, full_output, epsabs, epsrel, limit, points)
    370 def _quad(func,a,b,args,full_output,epsabs,epsrel,limit,points):
    371     infbounds = 0
--> 372     if (b != Inf and a != -Inf):
    373         pass   # standard integration
    374     elif (b == Inf and a != -Inf):

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

When I try to let it return values corresponding to an array of integration endpoints.  I considered that the function `integrate.quad` is not suited to take an array as the integration endpoint, but is there a suitable alternative?

I am using Python 3.6.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The third parameter of [`piecewise`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.piecewise.html) is supposed to be

> list of callables, f(x,*args,**kw), or scalars

and `x[x < ul]` is neither. As written, even a single evaluation `f_cdf(3)` fails for this reason.

If using a callable there,

```
f_pdf = lambda x: np.piecewise(x, [x < ul, x >= ul], [lambda x: x, 0])
```

evaluation of `f_cdf(3)` works, returning `(0.49999999999999994, 5.551115123125782e-16)`. You probably only want the first part of this tuple, and not the second one, which is an estimate for integration error. So use

```
f_cdf = lambda x: integrate.quad(f_pdf, 0, x)[0]
```

Since [`quad`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.quad.html) does not accept an array as its third argument (it must be a float), an attempt to pass X to `f_cdf` will fail.  A lazy way to deal with this is to slap `vectorize` on the function:

```
f_cdf = np.vectorize(lambda x: integrate.quad(f_pdf,0,x)[0])
```

will make it possible to use `f_cdf(X)`. This is slow, however.

#### Integration with variable upper limit

A very fast, but not very accurate way is to use `cumtrapz` method:

```
print(integrate.cumtrapz(f_pdf(X), X))
```

is much faster than `f_cdf(X)` but the output has noticeable errors of integration.

To get an accurate result, one can write a `for` loop that performs integration with `quad` over very short intervals from X[i-1] to  X[i] and adds the result. This won't easily fit in a one-line `lambda`, however.

#### Precision issue

Your integrand `f_cdf` is discontinuous at `ul`, which hurts the precision of integration. To improve the precision, provide `points=[ul]` parameter when it falls in the range of integration. Like this:

```
integrate.quad(f_pdf, 0, x)[0] if x < ul else integrate.quad(f_pdf, 0, x, points=[ul])[0]
```

Comment: @6-white-male in your second non-code line did you mean `f_pdf(3)`  I agree with that.  I'm curious as to why it *seemed* to work as originally written when I gave that function a numpy array.

Comment: @6-white-male your shortcut using `np.vectorize` seems to work well but there is numerical instability after the upper limit the integral should be constant however some function evaluations fluctuate to `0.49999997` and some have upward fluctuations.  I eventually tried `f_cdf = np.vectorize(lambda x: integrate.quad(f_pdf,0,x,epsabs=1e-15,limit=100)[0])` because I thought changing the tolerance and/or the amount of subintervals would make the answer more precise.  The results changed a little but I was not able to get better than 8-digit precision.

Answer (score 0):

Please always give the full traceback of your any error so that we can actually know where it's not working.

From the error however I can already say that when you write `np.piecewise(x, [x < ul, x >= ul], [x[x<ul],0])`, the logical tests you are running on your arrays are the problem. Namely, when you write `x < ul`, do you mean that all values in `x` must be so that `x[i] < ul[i]`? Do you mean that at least one value satisfies this condition?

The fix to that problem is basically given by the error: write any logical tests between array within a `np.all()` or `np.any()` function, for example `np.all(x < ul)` if you want all values in `x` to be less than values in `ul` in the same position.

Comment: as you can see the `np.piecewise` portion is working as expected despite your comment.  Can you explain how I should modify the use of the `np.piecewise` function given the evaluation I need?  Linear function for any argument less than `ul`, zero otherwise.

Comment: I was sort of guessing from the only logical test I was seeing here... My explanation of the error stands though: `_quad` is trying to compare the value of an array to `Inf` (through the parameter you passed), which is making me think that `_quad` is designed to be used with arrays. If you want to evaluate `_quad` for several values, I think the simplest way will be to loop over the values of `x` and call `_quad` for each value.